# Test object has a value in it or not in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one class in javascript :

```
function Quotation(){
  if(typeof Quotation.instance === 'object'){
    return Quotation.instance;
  }
  Quotation.instance = this;
  var self = this;

  this.getQuotation = function(customerID,numRow){
      var result = "";
      var urlDefault = "mysite.com/getDefaultQuote" + "?id="+ customerID +"&count=" + numRow;
      var url = "mysite.com/getQuote" + "?id="+ customerID +"&count=" + numRow;
      $.ajax({
         url:url,
         type:type,
         dataType:datatype,
         contentType: contenttype,
         data : JSON.stringify(data),
         success:function(res){
         result = res;
       },
       error:function(res){
         result="";
       },
       async : false
     });
     return result;    
  };
}
```

This is where my view call `Quotation` object :

```
 var quotation = new Quotation();
 var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {

    },
    render: function(){
        console.log(quotation.getQuotation(10,12));
    }
});
```

I want to test in `getQuotation` :

if `quotation.getQuotation(10,12)` has value in it, then `getQuotation` will take `url = "mysite.com/getQuote"` as an ajax request URL.

Otherwise if `quotation.getQuotation(10,12)` no record, then `getQuotation` will take `urlDefault = "mysite.com/getDefaultQuote";`.

Here the result in the console :

[image]
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does it print in the console?

Comment: @thefourtheye : I added in the question. Thanks.

Comment: But where are you using `customerID` and `numRow`?

Comment: My bad, it presents in url, I updated it.

Comment: What do you mean by has value?

Comment: @AlexShilman I meant, the object contains any records from database, it is not null.

Answer (score 1):

You should check `res` inside the `success` callback and perform an extra AJAX request to load the default quote when `res` is `null`.

I would probably implement this logic server-side so that you always perform a single request.